# Display div right next to centered text

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code

```
<div id='main'>
    Question Title
    <div id='tooltip'>?</div>
</div>
```

`Question Title` is centered inside of the `main` container. I want my `tooltip` div to appear right next to the centered text inside my main container, while the main container can be arbitrarily large. How can I achieve this? I found similar issues on SO but none of the solutions actually worked for my case

Comment: do you mean : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvXBZE ?  You might need to use class to reuse it a few times instead ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the display property of the #tooltip div to "inline-block". This will make it appear directly after the text on the same line

Comment: Yes, I only tried `block` and that didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use SPAN instead of DIV.

```
<div id='main'>
    Question Title
    <span id='tooltip'>?</span>
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp5kmykw/)

Or keep the DIV but change its Display property to "inline-block"
[Like this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/u48vebx4/)